# Flashproblems using specialcharacters (å,ä,ä etc) from database

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, utf-8, flash-cs3, utf8-decode

I have a problem with a flashpage I am developing. It sends a request to a database through a php-file and retrieve a text that I place in a textfield. The problem is that the swedish and other specialcharacters is shown in code format looking like this \u00e4 . I know both my php-file and database is correct because I have used the same request with the same php-file and database in a android app and it works perfect.

Do anyone know if there is some kind of code as utf-8 or simular function in flash actionscript 3.0 in cs3.

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); 

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","db","psw");
if(!$con)
{
die(' not working: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);
mysql_set_charset('utf8');

if($_REQUEST['sort']=='categories'&&$_REQUEST['prg']=='flash')
{
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$_REQUEST['sort']." ORDER BY id");
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) //assoc
     $output[]=$e;
echo $output;
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

Thanks for the help/micke

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple escape() on your string before sending it away.

```
escape("\u00e4"); // returns %20%E4, which php should interpret as "ä"
```

Potentially in php a `urldecode()` may be required.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. I have tried to save php file as ansi, utf-8 and unicode and tried a lot of decoding. I attached the php-file in the question. Maybe I should remove the header and/or the mysql_set_charset(utf-8)?